# Terminal Services -: Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: c#, remote-desktop, terminal-services

Test driving a remote desktop feature in an app but keep getting a weird error with the server name I'm putting in.

**Code:**

```
        rdp.Server = txtServer.Text;
        rdp.UserName = txtUser.Text;
        IMsTscNonScriptable secured = (IMsTscNonScriptable)rdp.GetOcx();
        secured.ClearTextPassword = txtPass.Text;
        rdp.Connect();
```

**Keep getting the error:**

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in AxInterop.MSTSCLib.dll

Additional information: Value does not fall within the expected range.
```

**On line:**

```
 rdp.Server = txtServer.Text;
```

**txtServer.Text is being input as (but with a real address):**

```
123.456.789.10:1234
```

Anybody else had this issue?

**EDIT**

The issue is with the port in the address, how can I get around this?

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, good of you to leave a comment as to why too..

Comment: There should be an .AdvancedSettings.RDPPort property where you can set the port there. Look at [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43705/Remote-Desktop-using-C-NET?fid=1551804&fr=26#4643566), specifically at page 2 of the comments.

Comment: @icemanind Make that an answer, that worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be an `.AdvancedSettings.RDPPort` property where you can set the port. Look at [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43705/Remote-Desktop-using-C-NET?fid=1551804&fr=26#4643566), specifically page 2 of the comments.

Comment: @ParanoidAndroid I can't find any properties like .RDPPort in .AdvancedSettings. Can u please assist me on this.